# Does a soul being resurrected know what spell is being used?

Tags: dnd-5e, resurrection, soul

Specifically, would a soul know that the body they're being invited into was created via Reincarnate? After all, for some souls, changing species might be a big deal, possibly of the 'rather stay dead' kind.

Answer (score 15):

### The soul knows the body before it chooses to enter it

The [*reincarnate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/reincarnate) spell states:

> You touch a dead humanoid or a piece of a dead humanoid. Provided that the creature has been dead no longer than 10 days, the spell forms a new adult body for it and then **calls the soul to enter that body.** If the target's soul isn't free or willing **to do so,** the spell fails. [...]

The "do so" refers to "entering that body" meaning the body created by the spell. Thus, the soul must be willing to enter the specific body created by the spell; this means the soul can decide that it does not like the body and refuse to enter it. The caster could then try again if they so choose, provided they expend another 1000gp of materials.

Comment: Hmm, this raises an odd question: If the spell fails due to an unwilling soul, then what happens to the created body? I suppose it doesn't really matter, mechanically speaking, so the DM could decide based on what is appropriate for the setting. Maybe it dissolves back into nothing, or maybe it sticks around like a corpse.

Comment: This doesn't answer the main question. "Does a soul being resurrected know what spell is being used?"

Comment: @eternal I honestly don't think that's even being asked here given the body of the question. Yes, it's in the title but the question is asking specifically about *reincarnate*

Comment: True, but for a complete answer maybe include an answer for the title question as well? If only for people searching for an answer for whats in the title.

Comment: @eternal I might be more ready to edit this question's title and then open a new question, or, if one already exists, I'd gladly bounty it